# generate URL on node.js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, url

I'm looking for a professional technique to generate unique URL addresses. I created a node.js server that should give out these URLs to accessing clients.
How can I provide the URLs?

```
// user is connecting to www.privatebox.de

// server serves index.html with unique ID

// e.g. www.privatebox.de/8yfuzyzzm7
```

Comment: How about an example on what you're trying to do?

Comment: @ NilsH , thanks for reading, I now added some pseudo code

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For a robust solution, I would consider using node-uuid to generate UUIDs.

Install the package with NPM:

```
npm install node-uuid
```

Based on the sample code from the [GitHub project page](https://github.com/broofa/node-uuid):

```
var uuid = require('node-uuid');

// Generate a v1 (time-based) id
var timeBasedID = uuid.v1(); // -> '6c84fb90-12c4-11e1-840d-7b25c5ee775a'

// Generate a v4 (random) id
var randomID = uuid.v4(); // -> '110ec58a-a0f2-4ac4-8393-c866d813b8d1'

var url = 'www.privatebox.de/' + randomID;  // or + timeBasedID
```

If you're looking for a shorter, more url-friendly unique ID, then [ShortId](https://github.com/dylang/shortid) might be a decent option for you, although the chance of collisions will be higher. ShortId will generate ids like this:

```
ShortId.generate() -> 'PPBqWA9'
```

Finally, I suggest you look at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/how-to-create-a-guid-uuid-in-javascript) for generating unique ids in javascript.

Comment: your ShortId Link directed mit to the same page like the SO question Link is that right?

Comment: Sorry about that -- fixed link.

Comment: The one problem of ShortId module is '-' and '_' chars in short url.
A lot of sites convert them with urlEncoding and you can loose functionality.
I recommend to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/id-shorter (id-shorter) that free from this limitation.