# How to change URL for users using socket.io?

Tags: javascript, node.js, url, express, socket.io

I am making a game for TWO players with node.js, socket.io and express.

In order to avoid effect from the third person that come to play, i want to generate specific URL for the two who are ready to play.

So my question is, how to change the URL when two people have come?

I am now testing it in local. In the server side, i have server listen to a port.

```
 var express = require('express');
 var SocketIO = require('socket.io');
 var http = require('http');
 var path = require('path');

 var app = express({
   views: path.join(__dirname, 'views')
 });

 app.use('/assert', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'assert')));
 app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);

 app.get('/', function (req, res) {
   res.render('home.html', {layout: false});
 });

 var server = http.createServer(app);
 var sio = SocketIO.listen(server);
 server.listen(8080);  

 function(...){...}
```

In the client side, i have socket connected to somewhere.

```
 var socket = io.connect('http://' + location.host);
 var ....
```

i guess what i need to do is to provide a button when i detect that two clients come in.
When they clicked it, it direct them to a generated new URL.

So there is an old URL and many new ones...

Then how can i set different URLs in both server and client??

Any help is appreciated^ ^

Comment: So when two players have signalled that they want to play, you want to send them to a (unique?) URL for their game?

Comment: @robertklep, just redirect them to the URL with generated parameter, in order to separate every two players.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways for generating a UNIQUE random url
1) Use Timestamp and append it to a predefined url of yours
2) Use random number generators. This can be done either by pure javascript function Math.Random() or even the one provided by node

Eg.

```
var url = "http://www.yourHostName.com/"+(Math.Random()*(UpperLimit-LowerLimit)+(LowerLimit));
```

Supply Large UpperLimit Like 100000 (According to your need and expected traffic) and LowerLimit = 0;
or by using the time stamp like this:

```
var url = "http://www.yourHostName.com/"+ new Date.getTime();
```

Beside this as I said you can also use the node to do the same task. There is a module called node-uuid which can do the similar task Refer to this Question: [generate URL on node.js server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15691758/generate-url-on-node-js-server)

Once you have the unique URL and the reference to the clients to whom you want to send to a same Generated URL. Then Just Redirect them using the following:

```
response.writeHead(301,
{Location: url};       //one you generated
);
response.end();
```